# Quadrilateral into a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Consider a quadrilateral with none of its sides equal. Show that it is possible to use the four sides to construct a trapezoid.

I'm not sure what to do? Do I have to rearrange the sides or can I do it without rearranging them?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot deform quadrilateral with sides (1, 2, 3, 4) to trapezoid (excluding degenerate case), but can deform rearranged quadrilateral with sides (1, 2, 4, 3), so the second assumption is not always feasible.
[play here](http://mr.nestynunez.com/quadrilaterals/)